# Cannot add a new user

Tags: users, user-management

I am trying to add a new user to my ubuntu 14.04 os. I go System Settings -> User Accounts and try to click the [+] button, but nothing happens it is grayed out. The system did not ask me for administrator password, why? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing right. There is no bug other than bug in GUI design - there is an *Unlock* button in the upper right corner of the *User Accounts* window, but it is hardly noticeable. Click it and you will be asked for password, and the [+] and [-] keys will be enabled.

You can also add a new user account via command line:

`sudo adduser johndoe`

It will create a new user as well.

Answer (score 7):

You haven't unlocked it.

Go to users.

[image]

Click unlock.

[image]

Enter your password.

[image]

Click add.

[image]

Enter the details.

[image]

My pronouns are He / Him